# What is code section?

Tags: windows, assembly

In which context does the terms `code section`, `data section` apply? Is it part of a Win32 process or it is part of a Windows portable exe? 
In C, does a function pointer refer to an address in the code section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [Wikipedia article on the Portable Executable (Window .EXE) format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Layout). In particular, the *Layout* section.

Comment: so it is part of the exe and it is mapped to the in memory process. Is that correct?

Comment: In general, yes. To answer your question about the function pointer, it could be an indirect pointer to the `.text` section (what you called the "code section"), so maybe not necessarily a direct address, but will probably resolve to a direct address eventually.

Answer (score 2):

It is part of the portable executable format specification. However, the majority of file formats also have the section abstraction. In fact, this is why you see libraries such as BFD which provide a view of this common abstraction.

Each section can have certain flags describing what sort of access it has. Typically a data section might have read/write but no execute access, whereas a code section might have read/execute but not write access. There are common names for sections such as `.text` for the code section, but there is nothing mandating that the section must be named like this. In fact, some aggressive executable packers will strip section names.

The sections are defined at compile time, and the dynamic linker uses this information to decide how to map the program into memory, setting page protections, etc.